# USB3.1 solder directly to receptacle

Tags: usb, cables, usb-device, usb-c

I have a device (memory card) that has a USB 3.1 receptacle type-C connector. We would like to solder a USB 3 cable directly to the receptacle pads.  We have used the following diagram:

[Link to diagram](https://somanytech.com/usb-c-3-0-wiring-diagram-schematics-assembly-diagram-usb-c-color-code/)
[image]

We think that the footprint of the connector is (we don't have the connector's PN, but it seems to be the right one):
[image: Footprint]

We also added the needed capacitor and resistor as shown in the diagram

The other side of the cable is a USB 3 type A male that connects to a PC.

After soldering the wires we get only USB 2 speed.

We have tried to cross the RX and TX data lines, and also changed the resistor to pull-down; all this didn't give better results.

Comment: Which USB memory card?

Comment: USB 3.1 is pretty fussy, have you checked you've matched your impedances etc? Are you sure the memory card runs at USB 3 speeds? Are you sure the PC runs at USB 3 speeds? Have you checked the sheilding etc? Have you got a photograph of your end result?

Comment: we Use ASUS ROG STRIX M.2 converter with Samsung 500G; the cable that we use is a USB3 cable that we cut off the type-C male and expose the wires, we have connected the main shield to the board, also we saw that there is a drain for the TX and RX differential pairs, we connected them to GND; we have tested the PC with new converter and standard cable

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: It's not a memory card, nor a converter it's an SSD enclosure. Perhaps it would have been easier to just use the provided USB-A to USB-C cable and a blob of epoxy to make it permanent. Pull-down is wrong because then the enclosure can't detect connector orientation. You need to pull-up correct CC pin and have correct pair swap and pair polarity.

Comment: we are soldering the wires to have stronger connection; we can't use the original type-C connectors, the requirement for this project is to have a wire soldered to the converter

Answer (score 2):

It Works!

so, after testing a few connection options, we have found out the proper connection

Black + Shield - pin A1

Yellow         - pin A2

Blue           - pin A3

Green          - pin A6

White          - pin A7

Red            - A9

Orange         - pin B10

Purple         - B11

Shield         - B1

Capacitor 10nF - Pin A1 and Pin A9

Resistor 56k   - Pin A5 and Pin A9

speed tested 350M as should be at USB3.0 speed

thank you for helping